# .htaccess: RewriteRules working for /*.php are not working for /index.php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod-rewrite to make my URLs prettier. Everything is working finde except for `index.php`.

Every php-file gets parameter for the language, e.g. `contact.php?lang=de`. The file can be called by `/contact/de`. Since `en` is the default language, it should not occur in the URL: `/contact`. This is working fine. The same should apply for `ìndex.php?lang=...` with the difference, that the English (default) version is `/` (instead of `/index`) and the German version is `/index/de` (the same as for contact).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# No trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ htt p://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule contact$        contact.php?lang=en [L]     # default language
RewriteRule contact/(.*)$   /contact.php?lang=$1 [L]    # any other language

# default language (don't show any thing in the URL)
RewriteRule index/en$       / [L,R=301]

# requesting /index.php, one should be forwarded to /
RewriteRule index.php$      / [L,R=301]

RewriteRule /$              index.php?lang=en [L]       # default language
RewriteRule index/(.*)$     /index.php?lang=$1 [L]      # any other language
```

`http://domain/index/en` is working properly, i.e. the URL is forwarded to `http://domain/`. `http://domain/index/de` is forwarded to `http://domain/?lang=de`. This is correct but the URL should not be changed. Even if I remove any RewriteRule with `R=301` in my htaccess-file, the URL is still changing. I have to clue why this happens. I'm doing the same that works correctly for `/contact`. Are there any implicit rules for index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# No trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule contact$        contact.php?lang=en [L,QSA]     # default language
RewriteRule contact/([^/]+)/?$   contact.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]    # any other language

# default language (don't show any thing in the URL)
RewriteRule index/en$       / [L,R=301]

# requesting /index.php, one should be forwarded to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^/?$             index.php?lang=en [L,QSA]       # default language
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/?$     /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]      # any other language
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out some of my mistakes (such as forgetting the NE-flag). But even when I copy your rules one-to-one, it doesn't work. Could you mabe point out what I'm doing wrong in my code or explain why `http://domain/index/de` is forwarded to `http://domain/?lang=de`?

Comment: Your rule was not working because you are not using `THE_REQUEST` variable. In absence of this your REQUEST URI gets overwritten by last rule to `/index.php?lang=de` and that when `mod_rewrite` loops again it becomes `http://domain/?lang=de` (due to your index.php removal rule). I believe you need to test my suggested .htaccess in a new browser to avoid old cache.